# errors during run-app

Tags: android, email, sendmail, mail-sender

Hello i have got app which sending emails automaticly when countdown finish. Its working but sometimes when app sending email in Eclipse LogCat showing some errors... Email is sended anyway but i dont want this errors here... can anybody look at it and tell mi what is it without posting my code?...

```
03-18 10:01:17.265: E/dalvikvm(3011): Could not find class 'javax.naming.InitialContext', referenced from method org.apache.commons.mail.Email.setMailSessionFromJNDI
03-18 10:01:17.265: W/dalvikvm(3011): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 505 (Ljavax/naming/InitialContext;) in Lorg/apache/commons/mail/Email;
03-18 10:01:17.265: D/dalvikvm(3011): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0017
03-18 10:01:17.275: E/dalvikvm(3011): Could not find class 'javax.naming.InitialContext', referenced from method org.apache.commons.mail.Email.setMailSessionFromJNDI
03-18 10:01:17.275: W/dalvikvm(3011): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 505 (Ljavax/naming/InitialContext;) in Lorg/apache/commons/mail/Email;
03-18 10:01:17.275: D/dalvikvm(3011): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0026
03-18 10:01:17.275: D/dalvikvm(3011): VFY: dead code 0x0019-0025 in Lorg/apache/commons/mail/Email;.setMailSessionFromJNDI (Ljava/lang/String;)V
03-18 10:01:17.285: D/dalvikvm(3011): VFY: dead code 0x0028-0033 in Lorg/apache/commons/mail/Email;.setMailSessionFromJNDI (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: what version of android are you using ?

Comment: i have got xperia X10 mini with android 2.3.5